# How to manually order the set size bar plot of UpsetR

Tags: r, upsetr

I have the following code:

```
library(UpSetR)

listInput <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), 
                  two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10),
                  three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13))

upset(fromList(listInput))
```

which produces this plot:

[image]

As you can see currently the barplot on the left is ordered according to size.
I'd like to order it from top to bottom as: `three, two, one`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually order the sets by inputting them manually to `set` and setting `keep.order=TRUE`

```
upset(fromList(listInput[c(1,2,3)]), 
      keep.order = T, 
      sets = c("one", "two", "three"))
```

[image]

Comment: but what if we want to order the points in the plots too
in this plot we see the black dot of "three" then "one" then "two". How can we see "three", "two" and "one" ?!

Answer (score 0):

To keep both parts of the plot in your pre-defined order, you also want to use the `order.by = "degree"` option.

```
upset(fromList(listInput[c(1,2,3)]), 
      keep.order = T, order.by = "degree",
      sets = c("one", "two", "three"))
```